# Unable to remove items using splice within for loop in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, splice

I am trying to remove an item from an existing array using splice but is not working as expected. I even tried using filter instead of splice but got the same output. Can some one please take a look at the functionality here and help me figure out the issue.

Please try to add the available items here - https://08b11a0437.stackblitz.io/products then navigate to the cart page and try to remove each item. The items are not getting removed as expected.

Relevant Code is available in cartservice.ts, cartcomponent.ts(removeProductFromCart()) and cartcomponent.html - https://stackblitz.com/edit/08b11a0437?file=app%2Fcart%2Fcart.component.ts

Comment: You remove items from `CartService.addedProductIdArray` array but in template use `products` array which is not synchronized with service's array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are removing items from an array in cartService, but for the UI you are using values from the products array.

A quick fix is to reload your products array. Just add the following code in your `removeProductFromCart` function in `ShoppingCartComponent`. Add it at the end of the function.

```
this._cartService.getAddedProducts().subscribe((data: IProduct[]) => {
  this.products = data.map(item => item[0]);      
});
```

Apart from that there is another issue. You are hiding items in `ShoppingCartComponent` html using `*ngIf="removeItemId !== product.id"`. Consider you have three products (with id 1,2 and 3) in your cart, when the first products is removed, `removeItemId` will have 1, so the first product will be hidden. But when the user removes the second product, `removeItemId` will be set to 2, and now product one will be visible.

Comment: @ Anand Murali Is there any way I can modify the existing array instead of reloading the array. I believe this will cause performance issues as I had to send http requests all over again and would be a problem if there are tons of products

Comment: Yes. You have create the products array in CartService itself. And remove/add item to this products array. To bind to this array in html, just loop through cartService.products directly.

Comment: Got it Thank you